# Принимать звонки с телефона на компьютер

Tags: c#, телефония

Мне нужно подключить *SIM*-карту к компьютеру так, чтобы можно было принимать звонки и сообщения.

Что для этого нужно и чем пользоваться для написания принимающего звонки приложения на *C#*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужен телефон с полноценной поддержкой АТ команд или gsm (3g) модем. Подключаете и уже управляете с помощью команд. Почитайте про [АТ команды](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B).

Answer (score 2):

Можно на виртуалку поставить линукс, на нем установить asterisk с модулем dongle, управление по ami/agi/ari из .net-приложения на хосте осуществлять. А принимающее приложение как обертка для sip-клиента тогда пишется